# Why does Player name get printed twice by my code?

Tags: java, junit

**Main Class**

```
package main;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.junit.Test;

import lib.Die;
import lib.Name;
import lib.PairOfDice;
import lib.Player;

public class PlayerAppTest {

/* Please note - when we come to mark the solution to this unit test we will change the input
 * data set for the players added to the list to ensure the solution works dynamically based
 * upon any given data set and is not hardcoded in any way.
 */
@Test
public void testExecute() {
    ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    players.add(new Player(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"), new PairOfDice()));
    players.add(new Player(new Name("Fred", "Jones"), new Die()));
    players.add(new Player(new Name("Nila", "Singh"), new PairOfDice(new Die(5), new Die(5))));     

    String result = PlayerApp.execute(players, "Cassie Downturn");

    String expectedResult = "cassie, DOWNTURN\nnila, SINGH\n";

    assertEquals("The string returned should match the expected result (run 1)", expectedResult, result);


    /* Test with a second set of input data */
    ArrayList<Player> players2 = new ArrayList<>();
    players2.add(new Player(new Name("David", "Blunt"), new PairOfDice()));
    players2.add(new Player(new Name("Tim", "Jonas"), new Die(5)));
    players2.add(new Player(new Name("Remi", "Patel"), new Die()));     

    String result2 = PlayerApp.execute(players2, "Cassie Downturn");

    String expectedResult2 = "cassie, DOWNTURN\ntim, JONAS\nremi, PATEL\n";

    assertEquals("The string returned should match the expected result (run 2)", expectedResult2, result2);
}
}
```

Hello, this is the JUnit test which I have to pass, below is the code that I have written in my main package;

**JUnit Test Class**

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import lib.Player;
public class PlayerApp {

public static String execute(ArrayList<Player> players, String fullName) {
    players.get(0).setFullPlayerName(fullName);

    fullName = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <players.size(); i ++) {
        if (players.get(i).getName().getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains("a") || players.get(i).getName().getFamilyName().toUpperCase().contains("a")) {
            fullName = players.get(i).getName().getFirstName().toLowerCase() + ", " + players.get(i).getName().getFamilyName().toUpperCase() + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }
    return fullName;
}
}
```

This is the code in my main package, I am trying to print out the names which contain a char "a" in the first name, the first name should be lowercase and the family name should be uppercase. It should print out 
`cassie, DOWNTURN
 nila, SINGH` which is the names with a new line between them, however, when i print it, it prints the following;

```
cassie, DOWNTURN
cassie, DOWNTURN
nila, SINGH
```

I am confused as to why cassie, DOWNTURN has been printed twice as i cannot find the error in my code, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're trying to do way too much in your `if` statement and the next line. Try to get a `player` first, then create `lowerCaseName` and `upperCaseFamilyName`. That way your code gets much more clear, and you don't need to call methods multiple times.

Comment: Next time try debugging into the execute method. By stepping through the method you can see where your logic flaw is by watching what gets executed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to print out multiple lines, and then only return one name. The need to print them out is already disputable, but then returning a single item instead of a `List` is just weird. `execute` is generally not a good way to name a method, unless you're making a very macabre game.

Comment: I think he is doing debugging by print-statements. It's a good first step when trying to understand your code. We highly recommend starting to learn using the debugger though . It's quite nice to see what your code actually does ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You will print it even if the if doesn't match as it's outside the if-statement. Move it inside instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i <players.size(); i ++) {
    if (players.get(i).getName().getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains("a") || players.get(i).getName().getFamilyName().toUpperCase().contains("a")) {
        fullName = players.get(i).getName().getFirstName().toLowerCase() + ", " + players.get(i).getName().getFamilyName().toUpperCase() + "\n";
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth adding that the reason why this problem caused a name to be printed twice was that there was a name in the input (after Cassie DOWNTURN) that didn't fire the `if` condition, so that when the program came to print the name, `fullName` still had the previous iteration's value.

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement is not conditional and will always execute, move it inside the if. You're printing twice as your are not changing the value in fullName if the if condition does not evaluate as true. Further your family name comparison will always be false as you're comparing upper and lower case.

Your code can also be tided up and made easier to read:

```
    for(Player player : players){
        if(player.getName().getFirstName()).toLowerCase().contains("a")||player.getName().getFamilyName().toUpperCase.contains("A"))){
            String  fullName = players.get(i).getName().getFirstName().toLowerCase() + ", " + players.get(i).getName().getFamilyName().toUpperCase() + "\n";
            System.out.println(fullname);
        }
    }
```